# What is the use of three continuous question mark i.e ???

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit

I want to write one example using three continuous question mark. I have tried with one question but and I know how it works. but I am not able to find anything on using three question mark.

How cucumber will behave if I write:
I fill ???

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking about a step definition like `Given I will ???` or are you talking about a step definition like `@Given("^I will ???$")` ???

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was talking about step definition file.

Answer (score 0):

Within a feature file you can write:

```
Given I will ?
Then I will ??
And I will ???
```

And it will have any meaning that you assign to it. This will translate into these step definitions:

```
@Given("^I will \?$") public void step1() {}
@Then("^I will \?\?$") public void step2() {}
@And("^I will \?\?\?$") public void step3() {}
```

---

Within step definitions you can write

```
@Given("^I will a( and b)?$") public void step1() {}
@Then("^I will a( and b)??$") public void step2() {}
@And("^I will a( and b)???$") public void step3() {}
```

The first two step definitions match the sentences "I will a" and "I will a and b".

The last step definitions is invalid. It will raise an exception at runtime:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 18

Comment: Thank you for reply!   step1() would be called for both "I will a" and "I will a and b". What about step2(), what are the possible sentences? please reply. We can ignore third one as it giving some syntax error.

Comment: from the regular expression step2() will also be called for both "I will a" and "I will a and b"